# How to send to Amazon's Alexa Event Gateway?

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am trying to test sending an event to the **Amazon's Event Gateway** for my Alexa Smart Home skill using Postman but I keep receiving an 'invalid access token exception.'  I have read the [Amazon's documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/send-events-to-the-alexa-event-gateway.html) on this but apparently I am missing something.

When I enable my skill, my Smart Home Lambda receives the **AcceptGrant**.

```
{
    "directive": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Alexa.Authorization",
            "name": "AcceptGrant",
            "messageId": "b2862179-bc56-4bb2-ac05-ce55c7a3e977",
            "payloadVersion": "3"
        },
        "payload": {
            "grant": {
                "type": "OAuth2.AuthorizationCode",
                "code": "ANSVjPzpTDBsdfoRSyrs"
            },
            "grantee": {
                "type": "BearerToken",
                "token": "Atza|IwEB..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My lambda sends a POST to 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token' to receive the *Access* and *Refresh* tokens. It then stores those tokens.  Next, my Lamdba responds with the following:

```
{
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Alexa.Authorization",
            "name": "AcceptGrant.Response",
            "messageId": "b2862179-bc56-4bb2-ac05-ce55c7a3e977",
            "payloadVersion": "3"
        },
        "payload": {}
    }
}
```

I then get a message web page that I have successfully linked my skill - all is good.

Next, I try to send an event to Amazon's Alexa event gateway using the Postman app.  I put the Access token (I also tried the Refresh token) in the header as a 'BearerToken' type and the in the '**scope**' of the 'endpoint' object.

**POST** https://api.amazonalexa.com/v3/events?Content-Type=application/json&charset=UTF-8
with a header that specifies a Bearer Token (Access token received earlier) and a body that contains the following:

```
{
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "messageId": "abc-123-def-456",
            "namespace": "Alexa",
            "name": "ChangeReport",
            "payloadVersion": "3"
        },
        "endpoint": {
            "scope": {
                "type": "BearerToken",
                "token": "<access token>"
            },
            "endpointId": "MySmartSwitch-001"
        },
        "payload": {
            "change": {
                "cause": {
                    "type": "RULE_TRIGGER"
                },
                "properties": [
                    {
                        "namespace": "Alexa.ModeController",
                        "name": "mode",
                        "value": "Backup",
                        "timeOfSample": "2020-01-02T09:30:00ZZ",
                        "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 50
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "properties": [
            {
                "namespace": "Alexa.PowerController",
                "name": "powerState",
                "value": "ON",
                "timeOfSample": "2020-01-02T09:30:00Z",
                "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 60000
            },
            {
                "namespace": "Alexa.EndpointHealth",
                "name": "connectivity",
                "value": {
                    "value": "OK"
                },
                "timeOfSample": "2020-01-02T09:30:00Z",
                "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The response received is '401 Unauthorized'

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "System",
        "name": "Exception",
        "messageId": "95bd23c3-76e6-472b-9c6d-74d436e1eb61"
    },
    "payload": {
        "code": "INVALID_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXCEPTION",
        "description": "Access token is not valid."
    }
}
```

Comment: CAn you offfer some elaboration on how you generated your BearerToken (with that URL?) I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: i have same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I was mistakenly sending parameters: **Content-Type=application/json** and **charset=UTF-8** as well including them in the header - my bad.  You just need to include them in the header.

Comment: Hello "On the PERMISSIONS page, slide Send Alexa Events to indicate your skill will send asynchronous responses and/or change report events." In alexa skills page Im not able to find the Send Alexa Events button

Comment: Can you please tell me How do you send a simple "Hello world" message to Alexa asynchronously?
Do you need to use the events gateway? 
If so what should be the **endpointid**?
Can you please post an example of a simple async Response to ALexa through the event gateway, all alexa has to do is voice out the response that's it.
Many Thanks Please note I have reached till the part where Bearer token is received successfully and then access and refresh tokens too all are good.